# RFC6265, cookie can track the user between two sites, HOW is it possible?

Tags: cookies

In RFC 6265 [Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-7.1), it says:

> Particularly worrisome are so-called "third-party" cookies.  In rendering an HTML document, a user agent often requests resources   from other servers (such as advertising networks).  These third-party    servers can use cookies to track the user even if the user never    visits the server directly.
>
> For example, if a user(using the same computer and the same web browser software, IE/Chrome etc) visits a site (A.com) that contains content from a third party(P) and then later visits another site(B.com) that
> contains content from the same third party(P), the third party can **track** the user between the two sites.

[image]

I'm curious, what does it mean by **track the user between the two sites** ?

To be concrete...

- Assume I'm that user,
- A.com's html contains a <img> tag grabbing images from server P, and B.com does the same;
- I visit A.com in the morning then visit B.com in the evening;

Via storing cookies on my computer, P knows I have web browsing behavior in the morning as well as in the evening(no doubt), **but** can P know I browse A.com(instead of B.com) in the morning?

Comment: Not to worry you, but even innocuous sites like Stack Exchange do it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PbAp.png Lots of browsers automatically block them these days.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find it out, as hinted by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Third-party_cookie .

For a simple index.html like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
  <p>An image below:</p>
  <img src="https://chjfth.github.io/web/res/bg-pagehead.jpg"/>
</body>
```

When viewing it in a Web browser, it sends out such HTTP request to fetch the image file:

```
GET https://chjfth.github.io/web/res/bg-pagehead.jpg HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
Referer: http://10.22.3.84:5000/seeimage/index.html
Accept-Language: zh-CN
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: chjfth.github.io
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 13 Sep 2019 11:24:09 GMT
If-None-Match: "5d7b7c59-3534"
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Notice the `Referer: http://10.22.3.84:5000/seeimage/index.html` line, it tells the  third-party(chjfth.github.io) which webpage is fetching the image file.